# Is it possible to merge a smaller list into bigger list

Tags: python, list

Assume that I have 2 list as below

```
list1 = ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I merge the list2 into list1 resulting as below

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'NA', 'NA']
```

Using for loop replacing the item one by one will do the work but is there any faster way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use list slicing in `list1` to adjust `list2` between index `0` and `len(list2)`.

```
list1[: len(list2)] = list2
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'NA', 'NA']
```

Answer (score 3):

One obvious way would be `merged = list2 + list1[len(list2):]`

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop can do it for you. Make sure that the list2 is actually smaller then list1. Whenever list2 gets bigger than list1, this won't work anymore.

```
list1 = ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list1[i] = list2[i]
print(list1)
```

This prints out:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'NA', 'NA']
```

Answer (score 0):

using list slicing:

```
list1 = ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']



list1 = list2 + list1[:(len(list1) - len(list2))]
print(list1)  # output # list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'NA', 'NA']
```